# Easy loop to repeat a transpose formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to repeat the same formula over again for a column of data that I need to transpose. I have a macro which does the whole thing once. I have tried to create a simple loop, but I do not know how to increment the ranges.

I have tried a Do while loop, but with no luck on the incrementing part

```
Range("D9:F9").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(R[6]C[5]:R[8]C[5])"
```

So this code does the right thing, but I need it to repeat but the next time it should be Range D10:F10 and the Transpose should be R8 C5 R10 C5. It is this incrementation that I have problems with.

Comment: It looks like that using simple formula like:`=INDEX($I$15:$I$100000,ROW(A1)*3-3+COLUMN(A1),1)` in D9 and dragging it right and down should give exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    dim i as Integer
    for i = 1 to 20 'adjust as you need it
        Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(R[" & ?? & "]C[5]:R[" & ?? & "]C[5])"
    next i
```

I replaced the integer for yor transpose fuction with ??, I was nor sure what logic to apply.